# return File object from string

Tags: node.js

I know this question is really simple, but i dont found a "simple" solution to that.
IN some point of my code I have an array os strings that contain local system paths to files in disk, and I need to send to some class that need a "File" object to interact (send the text string return error told about File object)

I search in the node File documentation but I only found things related to read, write, create, delete, files, blobs, steams, etc, but nothing related to "how to create File object from file"

Comment: Could you be more specific about that class and the error you get ?

Comment: Im trying to senf files to https://github.com/webtorrent/create-torrent in the input param, but the file is created with wrong file name (take the name of the torrent itself, not the file), and because im using electron dialogs (return the files in array of strings not File objects) dont accept it. I try with new objects like {name 'filename.ext', path: '/var/www/filename.ext'} but is not a valid File object

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this, I don't know how to create a new File object, appears only created by the system itself when using file inputs or file system functions, but there exists 2 ways to solve my issue:

1. Create a new `blob/stream` object and add `object.name = 'name_you_want'` and this is accepted.
2. Create a new object like this:

`{name: 'filename.extension', path: '/var/media/filename.extension', size: file.size}`

The "trick" is the size key, if you declare it, and the path is the correct path to the real file (not the name you want) work.